# Define functions from two lists

Tags: function-construction

I have two lists

```
{G[x_,y_],F[x_,y_],C[x_,y_]}
```

and

```
{x*y-x, 3x+y, x^y}
```

Now I need to define 3 functions

```
G[x_,y_]:=x*y-x;
F[x_,y_]:=3x+y;
C[x_,y_]:=x^y;
```

How to do it correctly?

```
 Table[%%[[i]] := %[[i]], {i, Length[%%]}]
```

does not work

Comment: `C` is built in symbol. I'm assuming `x` `y` etc have no values. `MapThread[SetDelayed, {list1, list2}, 1]` but I don't think it is good idea in general.

Comment: What do you mean by I have two lists. Is `{x*y-x, 3x+y, x^y}` evaluated or it's just an InputCell`?

Comment: @Kuba It might not be a good idea but that's how one can do it, answer?

Comment: @Öskå Let's wait, maybe someone competent will elaborate something more than the quick fix I've shown.

Comment: @Kuba There you go, a more stable solution than yours ;o) Oh wait, it's the same :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given these lists

```
Clear[g, f, c, y, x];
list1 = {g[x_, y_], f[x_, y_], c[x_, y_]};
list2 = {x*y - x, 3 x + y, x^y};
```

one way is to just use `Apply`:

```
SetDelayed @@@ Transpose[{list1, list2}]

c[2, 4]
(* 16 *)
```

Would be nice for some context as to why the OP wants to do something like this. It might encourage better approaches.

Answer (score 3):

To be sure, you don't have naming conflicts with library methods, keep your literals starting with lower case. (More information on [Defining Variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningVariables.html)).

Otherwise the loop you try to do is done with [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html).

```
In[6]:= MapThread[
 SetDelayed[#1, #2] &, {
  {g[x_, y_], f[x_, y_], c[x_, y_]},
  {x*y - x, 3 x + y, x^y}
  }]

In[7]:= g[x, y]

Out[7]= -x + x y
```

Comment: Sorry @Kuba. Did not notice that.

Comment: No problem, but now you are responsible for this :p p.s. you can just use `SetDelayed`.